# Adding Material3 dependency conflicts with androidx.compose.runtime.livedata

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Have faced pretty odd behaviour with Compose dependencies.
I need

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha07"
```

But after it is added to the build.gradle and sync successfuly I have a variable

```
val someVal by viewModel.someFun.observeAsState()
```

where `observeAsState()` shines red as unresolved reference.
Of course

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
```

is also unresolved.
Removing dependency fixes the issue.
Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Found the reason to this?